# Как передать динамический массив объектов в метод класса?

Tags: java, arraylist

У меня есть динамический массив:

```
ArrayList<Person> arr_person = new ArrayList<Person>(count_persons);
```

мне необходимо передать arr_person вот сюда (где flag_validate - булевая переменная):

```
Validate validate = new Validate(name, pass);
flag_validate = validate.validateCheck(arr_person); <- сюда
```

Класс `Person` не наследуется от другого класса или интерфейса (мне это и не надо).

```
public boolean validateCheck( **ЭТО МЕСТО** ){
        ...
}
```

Вопрос, как должен передаваться этот массив?

Answer (score 1):

Внутри класса Validate:

```
public boolean validateCheck(ArrayList<Person> arr_person) { ... }
```